# Is it possible to sort a list of objects in Jinja2 based on subattributes?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

In my case I have a list of dicts that contains other several list of dicts.

```
l = [{
'a': [
    { 'b': 4}
    ]
}, {
'a': [
    { 'b': 3}
    ]
}]
```

What I would technically like to do would be to sort using the path ['a'][0]['b'] using the sort filter of jinja2.

Is it possible in someway?

Comment: Really you should do this in whatever Python code is rendering the Jinja template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: From a high-level perspective it's just a reordering of existing records. I think it may be acceptable to do in in a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your custom template filter.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters

Here would be a rough solution (no support for reverse, case sensitive, etc.):

Somwhere in your app:

```
def deep_sort(value, attribute, subattribute):
  return sorted(value, key=lambda element: element[attribute][0][subattribute])

environment.filters['deep_sort'] = deep_sort
```

And in your template:

```
        {% for value in l|deep_sort('a', 'b') %}
            {{value['a'][0]['b']}}
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `attribute` parameter in [`sort`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.sort), where you specify `0` as the first element in the list then `b` as the key of that element, and in your case you have `attribute="a.0.b"`:

```py
your_document_list  = [{
'a': [
    { 'b': 4}
    ]
}, {
'a': [
    { 'b': 3}
    ]
}]
```

```
{% for document in your_document_list | sort(attribute="a.0.b") %}
    ...
{% endfor %
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this in one line if you want:

```
l = [{
'a': [
    { 'b': 4}
    ]
}, {
'a': [
    { 'b': 9}
    ]
},
 {
'a': [
    { 'b': 3}
    ]
}]
print(sorted(l,key=lambda x:x['a'][0]['b']))
```

output:

```
[{'a': [{'b': 3}]}, {'a': [{'b': 4}]}, {'a': [{'b': 9}]}]
```

Explanation :

Using lambda you can access b's values , so basically sorted() will sort basis on a list of int here how:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x['a'][0]['b'],l)))
```

output:

```
[4, 9, 3]
```

sorted() will sort basis on this list.